# How do I get the function I pass through forEach to reference variables in other scopes?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I don't know why my **findDroids** function cannot reference the *result* variable within my **droids** function. When I run this code, I get "result is not defined".  Any tips/guidance is greatly appreciated. I'm new to Javascript, so please go easy on me :)

```
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
  arr.forEach(findDroids);
  return result;
}

function findDroids(value, index, arr){
  if (arr[index] == "Droids"){
    result = "Found Droids!";
  } else{
    result = "These are not the droids you're looking for."
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) //should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Comment: Because JS has lexical scope, and `findDroids` is not declared inside `droids` like `let result` is. Your question title already suggests that you know it's in a different scope - and no, it's not possible to create references to variables or pass them around.

Comment: Btw, `forEach` seems to be the wrong tool here anyway. I think you're looking for `find` or `some` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in JS `let` variables are scoped to its nearest function. In this case `result` is only available at `droids` level. Making the variable global should work:

```js
let result = ''; // Available everywhere

function droids(arr) {
  //let result = ''; // Available only at `droids` level
  arr.forEach(findDroids);
  return result;
}

function findDroids(value, index, arr){
  if (arr[index] == "Droids"){
    result = "Found Droids!";
  } else{
    result = "These are not the droids you're looking for."
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) //should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Having said that, using a global variable is probably not the best thing. You can find a `needle` in a `haystack` with `haystack.includes(needle)` to easily check if an array includes the value you are looking for:

```js
const arr = ["qqq", "www", "eee"]
console.log(arr.includes("qqq") ? "Found droids" : "Not found")
console.log(arr.includes("zzz") ? "Found droids" : "Not found")
```

Comment: "*Making the variable global should work*" - yes, but it's a horrible idea. Instead, move the `findDroids` declaration inside the `droids` function.

Comment: I understand there are multiple ways to approach this problem. Moving the variable to global did work. Also appreciated learning some new methods! Thank you for the tips. 

Answer (score 1):

```
function droids(arr) {
  return arr.some(function(a){return a === "Droids";});
}
```

The 'some' suggestion.  Check other examples for 'includes', probably a better tool for the job.